# TWA: Open links "in-app" with window.open and return to TWA afterwards

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm hosting a PWA currently quite nicely.

If I redirect from the page to an external one with window.open, another browser window opens and after closing the window, the state of the PWA is as it was before.

If I'm trying to achieve the same thing in my TWA app, the content of the TWA window changes, the chrome top bar appears and closing the window closes the app as well.
Using the android back button brings me back to the TWA but still with the top bar.

Am I missing something here?
Shouldn't window.open add another window on top?

Comment: This seems related to this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=947941

Comment: @andreban this seems to be it, thank you!

Comment: This issue has been fixed. If you test your app using Chrome Canary, the issue shouldn't happen anymore. It will make to Chrome stable soon.

Comment: @andreban already tried, thanks! if you make your comment an answer I'd accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems related to this [bug](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=947941). It has been fixed in the master repo and should make to Chrome stable on 75 (Apr 18th, according to the Chromium [release calendar](https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)).

In the meantime, it's possible to test the fix in [Chrome Canary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.canary).